# SVG animate d attribute mousedown and return on mouseout

Tags: animation, svg

I am trying to get this Emoji to frown on mouse over starting from a blank stare then return to the frown on mouseout.

Basically have an animate path applied from and to for a repeat duration of one then reset on mouseout.  I have read a bunch of articles but an confused if this using from and to vs animatetransform is the best.

Below is the svg the animation I want to include in without external CSS or Jquery.

Thanks in advance.

```
   <svg width="189px" height="189px" viewBox="0 0 189 189" version="1.1">
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-    rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
            <g id="unsatisfied-head" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
                <g id="g10" transform="translate(94.500000, 94.655027) scale(1, -1) translate(-94.500000, -94.655027) translate(0.000000, 0.655027)">
                    <g id="g12">
                        <g id="unsatified-head-box">
                            <mask id="mask-2" sketch:name="path18" fill="white">
                                <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                            </mask>
                            <g id="path18"></g>
                            <g id="head-container">
                                <g transform="translate(9.904041, 9.879125)">
                                    <g id="head-bg">
                                        <path d="M168.368696,83.9725634 C168.368696,37.5950106 130.678868,0 84.1843479,0 C37.6947798,0 0,37.5950106 0,83.9725634 C0,130.345177 37.6947798,167.945127 84.1843479,167.945127 C130.678868,167.945127 168.368696,130.345177 168.368696,83.9725634" id="path22" fill="#FFCC4D" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                                    </g>
                                    <g id="left-eye" transform="translate(44.568184, 88.912126)">
                                        <path d="M0,19.7582502 C0,19.7582502 0,29.6373753 9.90404093,29.6373753 C19.8080819,29.6373753 19.8080819,19.7582502 19.8080819,19.7582502 L19.8080819,9.8791251 C19.8080819,9.8791251 19.8080819,0 9.90404093,0 C0,0 0,9.8791251 0,9.8791251 L0,19.7582502 L0,19.7582502 Z" id="path26" fill="#664500" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                                    </g>
                                    <g id="right-eye" transform="translate(103.992430, 88.912126)">
                                        <path d="M0,19.7582502 C0,19.7582502 0,29.6373753 9.90404093,29.6373753 C19.8080819,29.6373753 19.8080819,19.7582502 19.8080819,19.7582502 L19.8080819,9.8791251 C19.8080819,9.8791251 19.8080819,0 9.90404093,0 C0,0 0,9.8791251 0,9.8791251 L0,19.7582502 L0,19.7582502 Z" id="path30" fill="#664500" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                                    </g>
                                    <g id="mouth" transform="translate(36.967823, 31.754472)">
                                        <path d="M74.280307,0 L4.95202046,0 C2.21850517,0 0,2.20798446 0,4.93956255 C0,7.67114064 2.21850517,9.8791251 4.95202046,9.8791251 L74.280307,9.8791251 C77.0187743,9.8791251 79.2323274,7.67114064 79.2323274,4.93956255 C79.2323274,2.20798446 77.0187743,0 74.280307,0" id="path34" fill="#664500" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                                        <animate  attributeType="XML" dur="10s" begin="mouseoff" attributeName="d" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"

                                          from="M74.280307,0 L4.95202046,0 C2.21850517,0 0,2.20798446 0,4.93956255 C0,7.67114064 2.21850517,9.8791251 4.95202046,9.8791251 L74.280307,9.8791251 C77.0187743,9.8791251 79.2323274,7.67114064 79.2323274,4.93956255 C79.2323274,2.20798446 77.0187743,0 74.280307,0" 

                                          to="M0.990404093,0.98791251 C1.87186374,0.192642939 3.18910118,0.143247314 4.13493709,0.844665196 C4.32806589,0.98791251 23.5567613,15.1693966 47.2175151,15.1693966 C70.8188447,15.1693966 90.1119164,0.98791251 90.3000932,0.844665196 C91.2459291,0.143247314 92.5631665,0.202522065 93.4446262,0.98791251 C94.3211338,1.77824252 94.5192146,3.08228703 93.9101161,4.08995779 C93.2713054,5.15196374 77.9794662,29.9880842 47.2175151,29.9880842 C16.455564,29.9880842 1.15877279,5.15196374 0.524914169,4.08995779 C-0.0841843479,3.07734747 0.10894445,1.77824252 0.990404093,0.98791251"/>

                                    </g>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors :

- your `<animate>` should be inside the `<path>`and `</path>` tags or you have to use its `xlink:href` property
- if you really want to see the shape animated, you'll have to make your destination shape with the same number of points your original shape has
- the `mouseoff` event doesn't exists, maybe you wanted `mouseup`

```html
<svg width="189px" height="189px" viewBox="0 0 189 189" version="1.1">
  <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill- rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="unsatisfied-head" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
      <g id="g10" transform="translate(94.500000, 94.655027) scale(1, -1) translate(-94.500000, -94.655027) translate(0.000000, 0.655027)">
        <g id="g12">
          <g id="unsatified-head-box">
            <mask id="mask-2" sketch:name="path18" fill="white">
              <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            </mask>
            <g id="path18"></g>
            <g id="head-container">
              <g transform="translate(9.904041, 9.879125)">
                <g id="head-bg">
                  <path d="M168.368696,83.9725634 C168.368696,37.5950106 130.678868,0 84.1843479,0 C37.6947798,0 0,37.5950106 0,83.9725634 C0,130.345177 37.6947798,167.945127 84.1843479,167.945127 C130.678868,167.945127 168.368696,130.345177 168.368696,83.9725634" id="path22"
                  fill="#FFCC4D" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                </g>
                <g id="left-eye" transform="translate(44.568184, 88.912126)">
                  <path d="M0,19.7582502 C0,19.7582502 0,29.6373753 9.90404093,29.6373753 C19.8080819,29.6373753 19.8080819,19.7582502 19.8080819,19.7582502 L19.8080819,9.8791251 C19.8080819,9.8791251 19.8080819,0 9.90404093,0 C0,0 0,9.8791251 0,9.8791251 L0,19.7582502 L0,19.7582502 Z"
                  id="path26" fill="#664500" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                </g>
                <g id="right-eye" transform="translate(103.992430, 88.912126)">
                  <path d="M0,19.7582502 C0,19.7582502 0,29.6373753 9.90404093,29.6373753 C19.8080819,29.6373753 19.8080819,19.7582502 19.8080819,19.7582502 L19.8080819,9.8791251 C19.8080819,9.8791251 19.8080819,0 9.90404093,0 C0,0 0,9.8791251 0,9.8791251 L0,19.7582502 L0,19.7582502 Z"
                  id="path30" fill="#664500" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                </g>
                <g id="mouth" transform="translate(36.967823, 31.754472)">
                  <path id="path34" fill="#664500" d="M0,4.9C0.4,0.9,3.6-0.1,5,0c0.2,0.1,19.8,0,43.5,0C72,0,67.2,0,75.1,0c0.7-0.1,4.2,1.4,4.2,4.9c0,2.5-2.3,4.9-4.4,4.9c-2.3,0-2.3,0-33.1,0S8.2,10,5,9.9C3.6,9.9-2.4,9,0.9,1.3">
                    <animate attributeType="XML" dur="2s" begin="mouseup" attributeName="d" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" to="M1,1c0.9-0.8,2.2-0.8,3.1-0.1C4.3,1,23.6,15.2,47.2,15.2C70.8,15.2,90.1,1,90.3,0.8c0.9-0.7,2.3-0.6,3.1,0.1c0.9,0.8,1.1,2.1,0.5,3.1C93.3,5.2,78,30,47.2,30S1.2,5.2,0.5,4.1C-0.1,3.1,0.1,1.8,1,1"
                    />
                  </path>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback! I tried making the points have the same count but it is still not animating the paths? http://codepen.io/pixelchef/pen/21aba2aee46a9c837d202236f3015426?editors=100

Comment: Hmm did it for you in the answers's snippet and your codepen works for me. Which browser do you use? Oh and because you set the `mousedown`on the mouth path, you have to click the mouth to trigger the animation

Comment: @Patrick, if you need the whole svg to trigger this click event, change the `begin="mousedown"` with `begin="Page-1.mousedown"`which should even be `begin="Page_1.mousedown"` after you rename `<g id="Page-1"` to `<g id="Page_1"` since there are some issues with `-` characters and xlink:href in Firefox : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdyyBL?editors=100

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @Patrick, if it solved your issue, please consider marking it as "accepted" by checking the mark at the left of the answer